# Do we really need a tag for each file format extension out there?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for avi, mp3 (we also have a mp3-tag :/ ), mp4, mkv, jpg, png, doc, xls, ppt, odf, large etc. Are all of them really necessary?

I mean, take [avi most upvoted question](https://askubuntu.com/q/83161/169736), what is the question about? Is "... relating to the Audio Video Interleave (avi) multimedia file format"? How about if I change the question from "use ffmpeg to transform mp4 to same high-quality avi file?" to "use ffmpeg to transform mp4 to same high-quality mkv file?"? Would the core of the question be affected? IMO, if I have to read the question by it most elemental components I would see: *How to covert X to Y using ffmpeg maintaining the same quality?* and for that I need to be a ffmpeg expert, no?

With the multimedia tags they are normally questions: how to play X kind of files, or how to edit X kind of files. I'm sure that X-player and X-editor may be a more fitting tag, which people may be real experts.

This is repeated trough all the other tags, [like xls](https://askubuntu.com/q/47660/169736) "Commandline tool for viewing xls files", how about "Commandline tool for viewing jpg files"? So, anyone knows any real use for this kind of tags? Or know any experts in these file formats?

Comment: If someone can generate a graph of "questions in each tag that are just general multimedia or transcoding questions" that I can spot-check, I'ld vote to dupe them all to multimedia.

Comment: Corner case - exclude some office format, because it's an outlier with generally legitimate specific questions.

Comment: Odd that, I saw the [tag:odt] tag being made earlier...

Comment: @Wilf this question actually has a lot of time in the backburner (since December) but that tag was the one that inspired me at last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with you. Within the realm of Ask Ubuntu a codec/container/file-format related question will always end up being about a program that creates, plays, views, edits, converts, and etc to/from that file type. Questions just about the codec/container/file-format such as how it functions or is laid out would be better suited for Super User since they aren't Ubuntu related at all. Therefore I think questions would be better tagged depending on circumstances with the program that is being used (eg: [pitivi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pitivi)), the type of program being used (eg: [video-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/video-editor)), or if OP is looking for a program then the [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) tag. I believe in tagging freedom, so if there are people who find these tags useful then great lets keep them, but personally I'd find it about as useful as tagging a question [computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/computer) and therefore my vote is that all of the codec/container/file-format tags be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Burninate all those tags since they're all busticated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Dupe all these tags to multimedia.

Answer (score 0):

The tags related to multimedia situation is just fine as it is.